# Could the cloning paradox be circumvented by inaccuracy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, wavefunction

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owPC60Ue0BE) by minutephysics, the idea of cloning two systems or structures perfectly is gone over and supposedly disproved. However, couldn't the argument be made that a perfect clone is unecessary, and that a functional clone is possible?

e.g. I have a kilogram of copper, and the level of precision required to replicate that kilo of copper is very low.

Would the cloning of functional copies be possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about physics. It is a question about semantics - viz. the meaning of an exact clone vs a functional clone.

Comment: @sammygerbil if you choose to ignore the fact that it is based on physics, sure

Comment: Where is the physics in your question? You are asking about what is "necessary" for something to be a clone. This is a matter of definition, rather than the laws of physics.

Comment: @sammygerbil the fact that the question is based on the cloning paradox, you know, a physics thing

Comment: As the video explains, the No Cloning Theorem (there is no "paradox") applies to perfect clones, not functional clones. So making a functional clone does not disprove the theorem, just as finding a black goose does not disprove a theory that All Swans are White. (The goose is functionally the same as a swan.)  ... Of course functional clones are possible. My socks are functional clones. So are my dessert spoons.

Comment: +1, excellent question. http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?t=109687 Tfw when posters on a web comic forum have better disposition toward physics questions than members of Physics.SE

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_cloning#Asymmetric_Quantum_Cloning

Comment: @sammygerbil I actually believe flawed questions have a lot of educational value, as they address common misconceptions and can help people understand better

Comment: if the test to know if a question is flawed or not requires to know the answer, then the measure of flawedness is flawed :-)

Comment: @lurscher I'm partially thinking about somebody learning about physics asking the same question and coming across this thread

Comment: @mcchucklezz Where do you think the physics is in your question? Just because you refer to the No Cloning Theorem does not make this a question about physics. How do you define "functional clone"? The example you give (1kg of copper) makes it trivially obvious that such "clones" are possible. DNA clones are much closer, but the video presenter states that the theorem does not apply to them either.

Comment: This clearly NOT about physics.

Comment: @lurscher The XKCD thread discusses stimulated emission as a cloning process. That is physics. This question asks about "functional clones" which are not defined. This is not physics.

Comment: It's pure semantics: what is a "functional clone"? I voted to close as well.

Comment: @Gert this is going to blow your mind, it's a clone, that is similar enough to do everything the original could. Almost like it has the same functionality.

Comment: No, it isn't "going to blow my mind" at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP's question can be reformulated with some rigor, and I am quite disappointed that phys.SE users have been unable to recognize this fact and are voting to close this question.

First of all, it is important to note that the no-cloning theorem means you cannot clone an arbitrary/unknown state. It does **not** state that you cannot clone states that are known. For example, it is trivial to go from $\vert 1 \rangle \vert 0 \rangle $ to $\vert 1 \rangle \vert 1 \rangle $. This means most of the comments regarding spontaneous emission are irrelevant.

Formally, there is no unitary operator $U$ such that $U\vert \psi \rangle \vert 0 \rangle = \vert \psi \rangle \vert \psi \rangle$ for arbitrary $\vert \psi \rangle$.

I believe the simplest interpretation of OP's question is the following:

> Given an arbitrary state $\vert \psi \rangle$ and $0<\alpha \leq 1$,
>   does there exist a unitary operator $U$ such that: $$U\vert \psi \rangle \vert 0 \rangle = \vert \psi \rangle \vert \phi \rangle \,\,\,\mathrm{where}\,\,\, \vert\langle \psi \vert \phi \rangle \vert ^2 \geq \alpha$$

If $U$ exists, one may naturally ask

1. What is the largest value of $\alpha$ possible?
2. Can you improve $\alpha$ by restricting input states to some subspace of the Hilbert space?

If $U$ does not exist (i.e. $\alpha=0$ for some, or all, input states)

1. If you divide the Hilbert space into subspaces, can you at least construct a $U$ that always gets you a state within the same subspace? Here we replace true cloning with merely getting something in the same subspace.
2. Are there other useful definitions of "approximate" cloning that can be used to construct a $U$?

I am confident this question has been studied before, and will update this answer when I find the answer to the formal question.

Edit: This has been studied at least by a few groups, the most popular reference seems to be https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.56.3446

Note that the definition they use is $U\vert \psi \rangle \vert 0 \rangle = \vert \phi \rangle \vert \phi \rangle$ instead of the one I wrote above.